# #<ActionDispatch::Request::Session:0xa8fde64 not yet loaded> error while accessing the rails application from ipad

Tags: iphone, session

I am getting "ActionDispatch::Request::Session:0xa8fde64 not yet loaded" when try to access the session in application controller.
It gives error when try to access rails application on iphone.
It's working properly on desktops browsers.
After login it goes to index page and I added before filter "admin_authenticate" for index page.

my sessioncontrollerfile

```
class AdminSessionController < ApplicationController
 def create
    if (params[:username] == 'abc@abc.com' and params[:password] == '12345')
      session[:admin_id] = 1
      redirect_to admins_path, :notice => "Login Ok"
    end
end
```

my applicationcontoller file

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

    def admin_authenticate
        if session[:admin_id] == 1
          return true
        else
          redirect_to "/login"
        end
      end
end
```

Not able to access session value set in AdminSessionController inside admin_authenticate method of application controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is solved.
By default cookies are disabled in iOS-7, if you enable the cookies you can access the sessions.